# NPM - Fork module, change code and send PR to author

Tags: node.js, git, npm, pull-request

For a particular npm package I want to create a PR with some code changes.. The author of the package told me, to create a PR from a particular branch..

All fine so far, I can change the url + branch inside the package.json and load the specific branch as npm module.. Also npm install works fine.

But then I want to change some code in that node_modules/module folder and create a PR from the code changes..

The only thing I can make to work for sure, is to first fork the entire repo in a separate folder, than checkout X branch, than change code, copy/past it to the node_modules/module folder every time I wanna check my code changes.. And than push it to my personal github page, and from there create a pull request..

But its really frustrating to copy/past my changes every time to the node_modules/module folder.

What is the best way to change a npm package and create PR for it, while still keeping the code inside the node_modules folder, so code changes can be checked?

Thanks!

Comment: ???? You just have to fork the repo for the module do the change in your repo > commit > push > do the PR ... why copy/past ???

Comment: Just click "edit" on github.

Comment: @SteevePitis, Cause it feels strange to do a fork inside the npm_modules folder

Comment: why did you want to fork the module there ? It is like a new repository !

Comment: Cause than whenever I change the code of that npm package, while still inside my project. I can check if the 'changed' npm module works like expected. My project makes heavy use of the npm package, so its like an instant test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `npm link`:

```
$ git clone your/npm-repo-fork
$ cd npm-repo-fork

# Link the project as a local dependency
$ npm link
$ cd ../some/other/project

# Use the linked project
$ npm link name-of-npm-dependency

# Now you can edit npm-repo-fork and the changes
# will be picked up by some/other/project
$ cd ../../../npm-repo-fork
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper thing to do. Fork the github repo, create the branch that the guy told you, make the changes and send a pull request.

If you want to work in parallel and assuming that there are no compilation steps that npm should do, you can clone the forked repository within your node_modules and work directly there. As soon as you will make and commit the changes then you can send the pull request.

**EDIT**

I would say that this can be an acceptable approach that can work on linux:

```
~/projects/your-project/node_modules
~/projects/your-project/node_modules/name-of-module (symlink to the ~/projects/your-forked-cloned-repo)

~/projects/name-of-module (It should be your forked repo that you 've cloned from github/assembla etc)
~/projects/node_modules (symlink to the ~/projects/your-project/node_modules)
```

Comment: Thanks @Svabeal.. But thats the confusing part.. Should I fork it outside the node_modules folder, and than clone it again inside the node_modules folder like you mentioned? Or just go to the node_modules folder, and do the fork over there?

Comment: @DutchKev - I suppose that you use github, assembla or another git provider. When you clone a repository, it is like you are copying it on your own space and then you have the permissions to do changes. Git will not allow to do changes in a repo that you don't have permissions. This is the fork part. Then you can clone the forked repo in any place you want. You can clone it in the node_modules or you can clone it outside. If there are not other 3rd party dependencies you can clone it outside and then create a symlink from the node_modules to the path that you 've cloned it.

Comment: Aah! It starts to make sense indeed :) The forking has nothing to do with 'downloading' the code, its just copy the code on your 'space', thus giving write right.. Than you clone (download) it into the node_modules folder, and from there you can push again to 'my repo'.. And from there create the PR toward the original owner of the repo

Comment: @DutchKev yes exactly. I've just modified the answer to include an approach that you can get if you are developing in a linux environment (possibly works for windows as well, but I don't know how to create symlinks on windows :P). This will cover the case of 3rd party modules that the module that you are modifying needs.